# default-address-pools is not recognized by docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, devops, docker-network

I am trying to configure docker-compose to use different network range by default, so I follow instructions from https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/29376

However, I get following error:

> unable to configure the Docker docker daemon with file
> /etc/docker/daemon.json: the following directives don't match any
> configuration option: default-address-pools

Here is the content of daemon.json - it is the sample taken from the #29376.

```
{
  "default-address-pools": [
    {
      "scope": "local",
      "base": "172.80.0.0/16",
      "size": 24
    },
    {
      "scope": "global",
      "base": "172.90.0.0/16",
      "size": 24
    }
  ]
}
```

Please advise.

My env:

```
# uname -a
Linux gfn-classroom 4.4.0-109-generic #132-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jan 9 19:52:39 UTC 
2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

# docker --version
Docker version 17.12.0-ce, build c97c6d6

lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
```

Comment: Note that 172.80.0.0/16 is not an address in a private space. Following youe config, your containers are prevented from communicating with that network in the real world.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pull-request https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/29376 was closed, not merged, so that feature is not available (yet) in Docker

Answer (score 13):

This is merged in https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/36396 and (hopefully) will be available in 18.06. [[Reference](https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/36396#issuecomment-391984724)]

Also note changing default address pool is also available as a cli argument, e.g.:

```
/usr/bin/dockerd -H ... --default-address-pool base=172.29.0.0,size=16
```